# Laptop Auto Shutdown After Power Off

Tags: windows-7, laptop, power-supply, intel-pentium

I got a used laptop from someone which works like a charm when on power but as soon as I remove the power cord and let it use battery power, it goes shutdown even though the battery shows there is 95% remaining with around 2+ hours of time.

Is this a battery issue or what? How can I troubleshoot it?

OS is Windows 7.  Processor is a Pentium M.

Comment: What happens if you turn it back on? Does it shutdown again, or stay on? Also, what version of Windows is on it?

Comment: No it stays on and works fine on power with the cord.

Comment: It's Windows 7 on Pentium M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as soon as the power cord is removed, it's not running on the battery. Seems battery is damaged. Try replacing with a new battery. Or else if you have spare battery, try with the spare.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off all Power Management settings in the BIOS and in Windows.

What happens if have the laptop plugged in, go into the BIOS and then unplug the power? How long does the battery last?

What happens if after you unplug the power, and it shuts down and you turn it back on WITHOUT putting the power back in.

You say it shuts down, does it run the shutdown process or does it just immediately turn off?

Comment: It just gets shutdown like it's without battery and I removed the power suddenly. It's acting like a child (desktop PC)